# Photo Management software which stores Profile / Bio Info

Tags: software, metadata, macintosh, photo-management

Looking for photo management software to do the following:

Image or multi images with the capability of adding bio/info for each profile.  For example lets say we have a model, and would like to have her pics and her bio and contact info with custom fields.

OS X mac software is priority, but would consider running VMware or getting a Windows machine for this

Comment: Related: [How to manage model information?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29621/how-to-manage-model-information)

Answer (score 1):

There is a ton of metadata you can enter on an image in Adobe Bridge, Lightroom, Photoshop, or any editor that lets you edit/add Exif and other metadata.  You can use Caption, Title, or the contact section that has job title, address, phone #, etc.  This will work on both Mac or Windows, so you should not need to go the VM route.