# Is it possible to obtain portraits free of charge in exchange for letting the photograper use the photos for his/her book?

Tags: portrait, pricing, portfolio

I'm looking to get some portraits of my nieces. They are good-looking girls but their mother (my sister) cannot afford to pay for a photo session.

I've heard that it is possible to arrange a setup where the photographer shooting the portraits can keep them for his/her book but the pics are also given to the model. Is this really feasible?

Comment: Even though the question as it is now is a bit difficult to read and understand properly, It has led me to a concept I did not now before, so I think it is a good question in that aspect. The downvoters should have stated why they didn't like the question. Agreed the question needs to be edited.

Comment: Since everyone is always worried why downvotes occur - _I_ downvoted this. This isn't craigslist, and the question would be better suited on that site. This is a Q&A site, and I downvoted because this does not fit the format.

Comment: Its updated wording is much better, no longer a CL ad, and makes it helpful for people to find out about TFP. I wasn't aware people did this to make portfolios, and would've thought it only appropriate to attempt with a close friend, before hearing about TFP.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, someone could do that. That is called [Time for print](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_for_print).

> "Time for print (also known as trade for print or test for print, TFP
>   and sometimes also print for time or PFT) is a term used in many
>   online photography communities describing an arrangement between a
>   model and a photographer, whereby the photographer agrees to provide
>   the model with an agreed number of pictures of the best photographs
>   from the session and a limited license to use those pictures in return
>   for the model's time."

Comment: Interesting concept. A short explanation on this site plus the reference to the external source would have made such a better answer.

Comment: @Jahaziel: Yes, you are right that the answer should stand by itself. I added a quote from the source as it looks right now.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/what-does-time-for-print-tfp-mean

Answer (score 2):

I am currently doing this so I can build a portfolio. Going to Craigslist and looking around for a photographer looking to build their portfolio would be my first stop. Like Guffa said, you might find it under 'Time for print' or any of the variations he mentioned.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Craiglist would be a good source for this. Look for TFP and please make sure to ask for a copy of their recent work. There are a lot of good photographers in Craigslist who are trying to build their portfolio but also a lot of predators.