# Finding Models in the US

Tags: models, locations

I'm looking at going to the US for a couple of weeks to visit a school friend.

Whilst over there to kill some time during the day I fancy a location shoot with a model as the landscapes are very different to what I can get locally to me.

*Are there any websites (or other systems) that allows photographers to put out casting calls to find models who wants to work together?*

In the UK photographers tend to use websites such as [PurplePort](http://www.purpleport.com) which allows photographers to put out casting calls asking for models, restricted to geographical location and allows you to provide details etc such as portfolios and the all important references.

Sadly the one I use is pretty much UK orientated, I was wondering if there was a US equivalent or an alternate ways photographers can find models to work with.

There's this question here [How to find models for portraiture?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19237/how-to-find-models-for-portraiture/43120#43120) however the last answer was around four years ago. In the UK ModelMayhem exist(ed), however the trend moved towards PurplePort at some point so am unsure if it's the same elsewhere. The answers again seem to be more angled towards TFP models ([What does Time for Print (TFP) mean in practice?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/what-does-time-for-print-tfp-mean-in-practice)). 
The other obvious answer is to go to some of the agencies representing nationwide, however from experience they tend to charge a fortune and a bit overkill for killing a couple of hours on a Wednesday morning!

Comment: What does "Not necessarily TF" mean? What does "...definitely not full on agency" mean? I suspect you're referring to who compensates whom and how much, but if you want someone from the U.S. to answer your question you probably shouldn't use lingo that is localised to the UK.

Comment: @MichaelClark TF is just an updated version of TFP as who prints these days. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Rather than vote to close, could people provide reasons why? The only think I can think of is the short lived (and even that's a stretch)?

Comment: I don't know.It seems to me that asking "what are the largest and most popular equivalents in the U.S. to PurplePort in the U.K. is an objective and answerable question, not particularly a "product recommendation."

Answer (score 2):

ModelMayhem is definitely the way to go in the USA. You have some newcomers, but they have still not the reach of the original.

Facebook, Instagram and Tumblr are great too, because models follow other models, so once you have found an US model page/profile, just go to the users she/he follows and to the suggestions.